# eBay 'Get Inventory Items' API NOT returning items

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to call this API with my eBay user auth token on the eBay API Explorer:

> https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item

The Headers:

```
Authorization:Bearer [MY_EBAY_SELLER_USER_TOKEN]    
Accept:application/json
Content-Type:application/json
```

Now I'm receiving this in response:

```
{
  "total": 0,
  "size": 0
}
```

Now I definitely have some items listed for sale and they are showing up on eBay. I also made sure that I am in production mode and that my auth token is also a production token.

What's going on with you eBay??? See image below:

[image]

Comment: Looking at the default headers, it's obvious there's a lot of stuff missing like X-EBAY-API-SITEID, X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME, X-EBAY-API-IAF-TOKEN, X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME, X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME, X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME, X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL. All of which appeared in the past but now is gone from API Explorer? eBay why do you have so many bugs???

Comment: see Api Test Tool for all required header

Answer (score 22):

So it turns out that eBay's Inventory API is fairly new.
Only items created via the Inventory API's can be queried with the Inventory API. Total waste of time.

Just use eBay's Trading API:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/index.html

To list an item:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/AddItem.html
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/AddFixedPriceItem.html

To revise an item:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/ReviseFixedPriceItem.html

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/ReviseItem.html

To revise price or quantity of item:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/ReviseInventoryStatus.html

Stupid eBay. All the quality engineers must have left to go work for Google or Apple. No support for json - still using tech from the 1990's

Comment: I didn't see this mentioned in the documentation and I've just spent two days struggling with their Rest OAuth2, successfully getting tokens etc and now I'm getting 404s in my inventory item. Pretty pissed off as you can imagine. Here is eBay's response in March '17 stating they are working on compatibility: https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/17883/cannot-get-my-listed-product-by-get-inventory-api.html

Comment: If your "old" items have SKU's you can migrate them using Migration Api. This will make them available to the new Api as well (note there are some restrictions on the listing as well)

Comment: They still haven't updated. It seems the new Seller API is isolated from the production environment & UI. Frustrated.

Comment: I would bet that ebay has the WORSTdevelopment team of any major company in the world.

Comment: This is still an issue to this day. We received this confirmation from eBay support recently, "The Inventory API is ONLY compatible with the Inventory API. Meaning if an item was listed using any of the tools available via the UI on eBay.com or was listed using the Trading API, they will not surface using the Inventory API."

Comment: And I just realized that we received a verbatim response from what you received in the [eBay forum thread](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/19687/get-inventory-itemlimit2offset0-returns-empty.html).

Comment: Thank you for saving my time.. Ebay APIs are a rabbit hole sometimes

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: @net_prog Yes, it's still an issue

Comment: Is this still an issue in November 2023? I have 10k items created by c# sdk but would like to migrate everything using REST.