# eBay inventory API: Get InventoryItems Always return 0 Results

Tags: ebay-api

I have a problem about ebay API.

When I call the inventory_item API  I get an empty result.
My request is

https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item?limit=2&amp;offset=0

Response body is:

```
{
    "total": 0,
    "size": 0
}
```

Then I call the inventory_item API By SKU, of course I failed again.

My request is:

https://api.ebay.com/sell/inventory/v1/inventory_item/80003953

（80003953 is my sku in ebay sell platform）

Response body is:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "errorId": 25710,
            "domain": "API_INVENTORY",
            "subdomain": "Selling",
            "category": "REQUEST",
            "message": "We didn't find the entity you are requesting. Please verify the request"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm confirm my authorization and sku are correct!

[image]
[image]

Comment: I could be wrong as I only use the trading API, but the trading API requires there to be correct headers in the request call

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are trying to get items that are created by Ebay-GUI.

This case was already discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849731/ebay-get-inventory-items-api-not-returning-items)

> So it turns out that eBay's Inventory API is fairly new. Only items created via the Inventory API's can be queried with the Inventory API.

In my case, using the old Trading-API solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, try the getInventoryItems API without limit and offset values.

If the value still returns 0 as count, try to gain new token for the Bearer and double-check with the actual account in the ebay website.

It may be that you are obtaining valid token, but from another account.

Else, try to contact the developers in ebay.

Comment: Hi Tichu, thank you for your reply. I can get orders by this token, so I don't think this problem cause by my token/(ㄒoㄒ)/~~ .

Answer (score 0):

The [getInventoryItem](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/getInventoryItem) (ie first url) call assumes that an item with the given sku exists, while [getInventoryItems](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/getInventoryItems) does not.

It looks like an item with sku 80003953 doesn't exist.  You will need to use [createOrRemplaceInventoryItem](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/inventory/resources/inventory_item/methods/createOrReplaceInventoryItem) to create a new one.